# Show PDF received from server with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, blob

I'm developing web application with javascript, jquery and nodejs.

I have to receive from serve a pdf file and show it in a new browser window. I think I correctly recieved client side the file because the window that is shown for the moment has the correct number of the page of the pdf and the correct title, but the pages shown are blank. This is my code:

Server side:

```
app.post("/showSlide", function(req,res) {

    var fileName = req.body.filename.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var course = req.body.course;
    var professor = req.body.professor
    var folder = path.join(__dirname+"/dataset",infoStudent[0].email,course+"_"+professor,fileName);


    var file2send = fs.readFileSync(folder);
    console.log("file to send: ",file2send);
    res.contentType('application/pdf');
    res.send(file2send);

});
```

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({"filename": $('#'+buttonId).text(), "course": courseName, "professor": courseProfessor}),
    url: "/showSlide",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {

        if(data) {
            console.log("data",data);
            var file = new Blob([data], {
                type: 'application/pdf'
            });

            console.log("Blob file: ",file);
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL);

        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status) {

        console.log("Error Showing File");

    }
});
```

Here the image of what I obtain in the new window.

[image: Window Obtained]

This is the first part of the output:

> %PDF-1.5
>   %µµµµ
>   1 0 obj
>   <>>>
>   endobj
>   2 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   3 0 obj
>   <>/ExtGState<>/XObject<>/Font<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 720 450] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
>   endobj
>   4 0 obj
>   <>
>   stream
>   xì}K¯e=nÝüê?±§·Þ`xv`d `d:[
>   ¤Û@þ~´¸øÐ¾÷"Ä6d× î!¥­%II¯ßýáõ·û»üýøû×õw÷úwÿû×ÿøñÛõºÞ×þ·Rkå5òõªízýåO?~ûÏóúóß~÷ÿòÏÿü§¿üùõó¯¯ßýa¾þúóÏñQ¹Z·þëßüøí?þøíõïÿñ÷¯×QcÒ¯÷SÿO¯¿üÓßRïïÞ^¥Ê_@Ô÷ÈH½¼GèÊí,íõQÞ3½ði Ô
>   ´wYýdM³Gòx·%E]3 önYýÝòëÝYijÒ²´gö×ÿmçÏí}¥³_¹ &û$çwÊÞ/¼_`¿6Ô£å» ÑÎíªräö^Í;fwÌÞ±,IÖ1+K[yvB;Vê{íüíz§%Û|BD*åÝÇþd½¡¼jSª7D}§$Õ#?{ÓwswYCX@£$*ïÆÉÝÓ#ñÎìwIÌ¨-òÏw¢ÎtV© ÜXù=!ÉîÐ*@}Ýä)tØPbS{j7Ë~­I¢~¯*k!É»ÉÞ"y#ÓµweAY37T!#äÎÑd
>   V(³?Å([_OR(yvg®rgµÙ'»YK$Ïr:É%Ø<è{uúäM3)´Ë*ÃI Í

Where I'm wrong in showing pdf?
Thank you

Comment: Why not just make a form-post to `"/showSlide"` using the `<form>` tag with `target="_blank"` instead of all this AJAX and blob-style complexity to achieve the same end?

Comment: What is the output of console.log(data)

Comment: @RajeshGupta i have added the console.log(data) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

An already tested solution:

Convert the pdf into a base64 encoded string (mandatory in some cases where the character encoding could be an issue as soon as you send it into a json), then send it to the client. In client, read the file like this:

```
if (data) {
    var base64DataUri = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data;
    window.open(base64DataUri, '_blank');
}
```